# FabricJs targetFindTolerance for horizontal/vertical lines

Tags: javascript, frontend, fabricjs

I'm creating lines and set the "perPixelTargetFind" value to true. If a line is diagonal, this works perfect, it gets found in the boundary of my targetFindTolerance, which is currently 20 Pixel. But if a Line is horizontal or vertical, it seems like the targetFindTolerance won't work.

Here is a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/droeqgro/

if you move your mouse close to the diagonal line, you can select it 20 pixel before reaching it, but if you try the same with the other two lines, it won't work. If you select f.e. the horizontal line and spin it to a diagonal position, you can't select it either in the 20 Pixel boundary.

Here is my code:

```
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    targetFindTolerance: 15
});

/*_____________Adding shapes_______________*/
canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 100, 200, 200], {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
    stroke: 'black',
    perPixelTargetFind: true,
  strokeWidth: 5
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 100, 200, 100], {
  left: 50,
  top: 250,
    stroke: 'green',
    perPixelTargetFind: true,
  strokeWidth: 5
}));


canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 100, 50, 200], {
  left: 140,
  top: 350,
    stroke: 'green',
    perPixelTargetFind: true,
  strokeWidth: 5
}));
```

For an example, see the Jsfiddle and select the three lines.

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in FabricJS. A hacky solution would be to override `containsPoint` function like that:

```
function fakeContainsPointFunction(point) { 
  var isTransparent = canvas.isTargetTransparent(this, point.x, point.y);
  return !isTransparent; 
}

canvas.item(1).containsPoint = fakeContainsPointFunction.bind(canvas.item(1));
canvas.item(2).containsPoint = fakeContainsPointFunction.bind(canvas.item(2));
```

See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/droeqgro/3/

Comment: thanks for your answer!
I'm testing your workaround, but when I'm clicking in the canvas but not selecting any object, the last line gets always selected, so you can't click in the canvas without selecting an object, which sadly won't work in my project like this. 
Do you think I should report my issue as a bug to fabricJS?

Comment: Right, I didn't notice it. I found a workaround which uses the internal `isTargetTransparent` function inside `containsPoint`. See the updated answer.  It seems to work fine but it may affect the overall performance since FabricJS uses `isTargetTransparent` when `perPixelTargetFind===true` so in this case the `isTargetTransparent` function will be called twice for each object. Anyways, see it works for you and yes, please report the issue to the FabricJS team.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Your workaround helped me a lot! :) I have reported the Bug to the FabricJS team.